# How can I fix the audio problems in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, lubuntu, music

Recently I installed Lubuntu 16.04 and everything was right until I tried to listen music and I realized that it freeze constantly, no matter what.

I solved the problem with the music (partially), starting to use CMUS as my music player, that help that music froze less, but it's still annoying. The problem is not only with music, I can't see videos (except in youtube), cause they stop everytime, it's a pain in the ass.

This is the first time that this have happened to me, I've installed Ubuntu Gnome, Xubuntu and some others before this, and they didn't give me that sort of problem (at least I don't remember).

I think that is a problem with the drivers, I tried to install Realtek HDA, tried to compile the package but gave me an error when I put make I don't know what to do, need some help

Comment: Just a guess but, have you try installing the restricted extras? `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: Thank you, but didn't work. I installed the Ubuntu Restricted Extras, as you said and reset the machine, just in case. Nothing happened, still the same